# Migrations from Models with Sequalize

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, models

I have models already done, and I need to migrate them. I tried the command `sequalize migrate:generate`.
Like this `sequalize migrate:generate` --models path (/models didn't work), but I do not understand how it works. Is there a way to generate them automatically or is not it possible? If so, how can I do it?

I Actually use node for my back-end

The project structure is like that:

```
--api
----models
-------mymodels.js
-------index.js
----migrations
```

My index.js:

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(
    file =>
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
  )
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// RELATIONSHIP FIELDS
```

Can someone helps me with this problem that I can't figure it out